# set tint of EditText error icon

Tags: android-layout, android-edittext, icons

Is there a way to set or change the tint of the EditText error icon? it is red with an exclamation mark. I want to set or change the tint to a color of my choosing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an easy way to change the tint color without replacing the icon. Fortunately, the material icon set in `Android Studio -> Vector Asset -> Clip Art` provide an error icon which looks similar.

```
val icon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)

// change icon color
DrawableCompat.setTint(icon, Color.parseColor("#F6CECE"))

// this is necessary, else icon won't show
icon.setBounds(0, 0, icon.intrinsicWidth, icon.intrinsicHeight)

// setError
editText.setError(getString(R.string.validation_required), icon)
```

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-edittext-custom-seterror-icon/

Answer (score 1):

you can use setError(CharSequence, Drawable).

```
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(nameEditText.getText()))
 nameEditText.setError(getString("This field is required"),iconDrawable);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I was aware of that method before asking the question. That method requires that I provide my own drawable, does it not? I just want to change the tint. Do you know by any chance how to access that drawable?

Comment: refer this link :https://github.com/sherifelkhatib/WidgyWidgets/blob/b20fcf0071019f6e3f325e3664489fc948edad0b/src/mobi/sherif/widgywidgets/EditTextWithCustomError.java

Comment: Is there a pre-API-21 version of this method? I do of course mean with the icon. I am using API-14.